# How to find records from 2 many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to find the businesses of a certain category inside a certain estate

I have the following models

```
Business has many Categories through Categorizations
Category has many Businesses through Categorizations

Business has many Estates through Localizations
Estate has many Businesses through Localizations
```

In the category show action I have

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @estate = Estate.find(current_user.estate_id)
  @businesses = @estate.businesses
end
```

The obvious problem is that it is returning all businesses for an estate no matter which category it belongs to. I tried to add a .where("category_id = ?", @category_id) but I get column does not exist error

Comment: Could you try `@businesses = @estate.businesses.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: @category.id})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems to work, here's the suggestion again as an answer :)

```
@businesses = @estate.businesses.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: @category.id})
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for the help. Is it rude to ask you to have a look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905220/how-to-use-active-record-reputation-gem-with-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: I've taken a look, hope it helps.