# How to use active record reputation gem with many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the active record reputation system gem.

My starting point was to display a list of businesses with their associated votes:

```
@businesses = Business.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")
```

Now I need to group the businesses by category and estate.

I want to display a list of businesses from a certain category inside an estate with their associated votes.

So I have the following models (many to many)

```
Business has many Categories through Categorizations
Category has many Businesses through Categorizations

Business has many Estates through Localizations
Estate has many Businesses through Localizations
```

I can get the grouped businesses

```
@businesses = @estate.businesses.joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: @category.id})
```

but I don't know how to get the associated votes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two might be chainable:

```
@businesses = @estate.
                businesses.
                joins(:categories).
                where(categories: {id: @category.id}).
                find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")
```

Why could this work?: Most queries in ActiveRecord actually don't return the objects, but an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that you can append queries to and use for further chained queries.

Comment: I tried something very similar to that but it didn't work. Yours does. Thanks again